# Shader - Transmittance or Absorption

Tags: opengl, shaders, directx, glsl, hlsl

I am trying to create a **transmittance** or **absorption shader** (glsl, hlsl, cg, etc...) in **realtime** but I don't find any good tutorial or white paper about this subject. I only find offline rendering references.

Is it possible to achieve this kind of effect in realtime using standard rasterisation of a 3D mesh ? How ?

[image]

Comment: For pure transmittance (no scattering) you can first render the back faces to a depth buffer, then render the front faces using that depth buffer to find the thickness (sigma) at each point and then calculating the transmittance using the Beer-Lambert law.  Of course, this will only work correctly in all cases for a convex object - you will have to use some kind of depth peeling or decomposition for complex objects like that statue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean by depth peeling or decomposition. I understand the problem but could you elaborate your solution ? Could you also elaborate your transmittance calculation ?

Comment: Decomposition means that you need to split your mesh. Depth peeling is a multipass technique when you render a mesh layer by layer. The simple transmittance shader can be found here https://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/xna-shader-programming-tutorial-14-transmittance/.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what rendering method you want to use. Standard rasterisation of a 3D mesh? Or do you have a volume representation of the model and your renderer uses that directly?

If you render a volume, check this:
http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch39.html

especially 39.2.

The effect in the picture you provide is mainly **subsurface scattering**.
Here's a shader for real-time rendering: 
http://www.iryoku.com/screen-space-subsurface-scattering

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I changed the question. I want to use standard rasterisation but I don't have any preference about the shader language.
I already found some references about SSS but it seems that there's a little difference between SSS and absorption or transmittance but I couldn't tell what's this difference.